# Will declaring @configuration on a class make it a spring bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I am having a spring boot project and I have a class declared with `@configuration` annotation.
will declaring a class with `@configuration` make it a spring bean ?. so here is my code below

```
@Configuration
public class DateTimeFormatConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
        registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new PaginationArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(new FlightFilterArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(new CampaignFilterArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(new ContactListFilterArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(new UserFilterArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(new PrimecastAccountFilterArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(new MessageHistoryFilterArgumentResolver());

    }
}
```

Will the above code results in the creation of a spring bean `DateTimeFormatConfiguration` in the application context when it is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `@Configuration` annotated class will register as a spring bean. Check the following snippet from documentation. The primary purpose of `@configuration` to act as a bean source.

> When @Configuration classes are provided as input, the @Configuration
>   class itself is registered as a bean definition, and all declared
>   @Bean methods within the class are also registered as bean
>   definitions.

[1] https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.25.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts

Comment: thanks a lot . i was thinking @configuration class merely serve as bean repository .